# How to validate form when user clicks elsewhere

Tags: html, validation

For the sign up form I am making, I want to validate passwords so that a user must enter a password that includes at least one capital letter and at least one number.

I have implemented this here:
http://jsfiddle.net/k9aHV/1/

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
                    <p><b>UserName:</b> <input type="text" required pattern="\w+" name="fname"/></p>
                    <p><b>Password:</b> <input type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{6,}" name="password" onblur="this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Password must contain at least 6 characters, including UPPER/lowercase and numbers' : '');if(this.checkValidity()) form.password1.pattern = this.value;"></p>
                    <p><b>Confirm Password:</b> <input type="password" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])\w{6,}" name="password1" onblur="
                    this.setCustomValidity(this.validity.patternMismatch ? 'Please enter the same password as above' : '');"/></p>
                    <p><b>Email:</b> <input type="email" name="email"/></p>
                    <input type="submit"/>
                </form>
```

At the moment, the field is validated only when the user presses submit.

How can I adjust my code so that the code is validated as soon as the user tabs or clicks away from the input field?

Comment: where is `setCustomValidity`, `validity` and other stuffs defined?

Comment: @AshishKumar It is defined onblur on the password input tag.

Comment: There its not defined, it is being used there. There must be the definition of this function.

Comment: see this: http://jsfiddle.net/k9aHV/2/ I have changed the validation on blur and its working fine **on password field**.

Comment: @AshishKumar, if you type in an invalid password in my jfiddle, then press submit, then you get the message "Password must contain at least 6 characters, including UPPER/lowercase and numbers".  This proves it is defined.  If you include capitals, lowercase and numbers and press submit, you get no such error message.

Comment: @AshishKumar, I'm not interested in producing an alert.  I want a message output like that occurs when you press submit.  See my jsfiddle as explained in my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, I got you. So the thing is, **you can not trigger native validation on blur**. If required, you can add custom validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger native validation on blur like so

```
input.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
    e.target.checkValidity();
});
```

The problem is you can't trigger the validation error popup programmatically.
One workaround is to programmatically click the submit button BUT the popup will only show the first invalid input element!

A more user friendly solution is to show the validation message in an element.

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gpnn6/4/)

```
var idx;    
var passwordInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="password"]');
for(idx=0; idx< passwordInputs.length; idx++) {
    //set custom validation
    passwordInputs[idx].addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        if(e.target.validity.patternMismatch) {
            e.target.setCustomValidity('Password must contain at least 6 characters, including UPPER/lowercase and numbers');
        }
        else {
            e.target.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    });
}

//code starting here is to show the validation message in a span element
function showValMessage(elem, msg) {
    var span = elem.parentNode.querySelector('span');
    span.innerText  = msg;
}

var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for(idx=0; idx< inputs.length; idx++) {
    var input = inputs[idx];

    //validate on blur
    input.addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
        e.target.checkValidity();
    });

    //show validation message
    input.addEventListener('invalid', function(e) {
        showValMessage(e.target, e.target.validationMessage);
    });

    //hide validation message. There is on valid event :(
    input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
        if(e.target.validity.valid) {
            showValMessage(e.target, '');
        }
    });
}
```